# How to add tooltips for items in kendo multi select

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

Please show me the way how to add tooltip for items which have a long length in kendo multi-select.

- Add a picture for more specific.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syA8Y.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[itemTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-itemTemplate)** and/or **[tagTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-tagTemplate)** and add a title attribute with the tooltip text:

```
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples", tooltip: "Apples tooltip text" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges", tooltip: "Oranges tooltip text" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
  itemTemplate: '<span title="#: tooltip #">#: name #</span>',
  tagTemplate: '<span title="#: tooltip #">#: name #</span>'
});
```

itemTemplate is item while selecting from the dropdown, while tagTemplate is the item once selected.

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/oLEkoQ)**

NOTE: you can use the same value for both the text and tooltip.

Comment: Thanks. However, it does not work. Additionally, I can not run your demonstration link.

Comment: @TriLeNguyenHuu, try codepen: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/oLEkoQ drop down the choices and then hover over one to see the tooltip

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm. But it is not for my problem. I want to show tooltips when users hover on the selected item in the KendoUI Multi-select. Moreover, you can view my attachment picture for more obvious.

Comment: @TriLeNguyenHuu in that case use the tagTemplate: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/oLEkoQ. This will give you a tooltip for each selected item.